# Is it possible to redirect output from PowerShell command to multiple log files instead of one Huge?

Tags: powershell, logging, output

I often face a problem with a huge log file, which is 1 GB in size and it takes hours just to open it.
I wonder if there is a possibility to split the output of PowerShell command into multiple, sequential log files, let say 100 lines per file?

Example:
Here is a PowerShell command that outputs folder hierarchy inside specified directory and count number of files in each.

`#Get Files with Full Paths ls -rec | ? {$_.mode -match 'd'} | select FullName,  @{N='Count';E={(ls $_.FullName | measure).Count}}`

If I simply append >MyLog.log to this script, it will create a gigantic log file.
Maybe there is a way to use a loop, counting number of lines and each time send output to new log file: MyLog01.log, MyLog02.log, MyLog03.log and so on, until the end, each having 100 lines?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear if you want to split the log file you already have or you want the command you're currently showing in your question to output files per 100 objects. please clarify. your question is very vague

Comment: Its not an direct answer, but you can split your whole file into smaller chunks like ```$i=0; Get-Content "C:\logs\MyLog.log" -ReadCount 100 | %{$i++; $_ | Out-File MyLog_$i.log} ``` . Also Instead og Get-Content New-Object System.IO.StreamReader will be faster.

Comment: To clarify, the goal is not to split the existing log file, but split the command output into multiple smaller files, instead of having one huge final log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always limit the logs to one day at a time (or one hour at a time).

```
$logname = (Get-Date).ToString("yyMMdd") + ".log"
>$logname
```